# nested pull with scala mongodb casbah

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

lets say i have a simple object

```
{
 "id":"xyz"
 "answers" : [{
   "name" : "Yes",
    }, {
    "name" : "No",
  }]
}
```

I want to remove answer Yes from the array

I'm trying something like this without much luck:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection

val searchObject = MongoDBObject("id"->"xyz");
getCollection().update(searchObject,$pull( "answers" -> ( "name" -> "Yes")));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `("name" -> "Yes")` as a `MongoDBObject` because look at:

```
scala> $pull( "answers" -> ( "name" -> "Yes"))
res10: com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports.DBObject = { "$pull" : { "answers" : [ "name" , "Yes"]}}
```

Which is not what you want, you want to pull a subdocument:

```
scala> $pull ( "answers" -> MongoDBObject("name" -> "Yes") )
res11: com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports.DBObject = { "$pull" : { "answers" : { "name" : "Yes"}}}
```